# Visual Studio Standard C++ 2008 autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-2008, autocomplete, visual-c++, intellisense

I feel a little dumb asking this question but I can't figure it out. When programming in C++ I want the autocomplete to show up like in VB or C#. Now I have to hit ctrl+space to get it show up and I can't get it to come up automatically. Where's the setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want autocomplete to show up after you type . or -> ?

This is under Tools / Options / Text Editor / C++ / General; check 'Auto list members' in the 'statement completion' section.